# Gradle systax error given code to generate random value

Tags: gradle

I get a syntax error of

```
Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ​dbPortBase
```

when I have this at the beginning of my gradle.build file

```
Integer dbPortBase = 5000;
Integer DB_PORT = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(999));
DB_PORT +=​dbPortBase​;
```

I'm trying to set up for ci such that I can pass a random port in for db port for use in Multibranch ci env. Seems to be valid java/groovy code. I don't know what is not valid about it.

I tried changing def to Integer, uppercase variable name, lowercase name, separation of addition a = a + b instead of a+=b no luck. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

it accepted this

```
Integer db_PortBase = 5000;
Integer dbPort = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(999));
dbPort = dbPort + db_PortBase​;
```